# JS interconnected molecular banner

Tags: javascript, css

I am looking to create a homepage banner that does pretty much this: http://liveplasma.com/ (takes a bit to load) but not in flash.

Kind of interconnected molecular looking effect perhaps with mouse over effects on a particular point/dot

Is it possible to create this in JS/CSS or other programming language? Would anyone know of a JS library that would have a similar effect I can take a look at?

Comment: 1 - Yes. 2 - D3. Finally maybe try google for a question such as this.

Comment: @Craicerjack I have, been looking for 2 days have not found anything yet. I think I just don't have the correct terminology for this type of effect.

Comment: https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Gallery

Comment: @Craicerjack thank you!